# How to optimize xamarin Treeview performence?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, treeview, inotifypropertychanged, stacklayout

So long story short, I wanted to create a treeview control but I got hit by a huge performence problem when there is many items. that was mainly because of 2 things, but I just want to ask you now for one.

So I have an ObservableCollection of type TreeViewNode that inherits from StackLayout (This is my treeView item source)

This the treeviewnode class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Involys.PraxisDemo.Controls.InCustomTreeView
{
    public class TreeViewNode : StackLayout
    {
        #region Image source for icons
        private DataTemplate _ExpandButtonTemplate = null;

        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private TreeViewNode _ParentTreeViewItem;

        private DateTime _ExpandButtonClickedTime;

        private readonly BoxView _SpacerBoxView = new BoxView();
        private readonly BoxView _EmptyBox = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Blue, Opacity = .5 };


        private const int ExpandButtonWidth = 32;
        private ContentView _ExpandButtonContent = new ContentView();

        private readonly Grid _MainGrid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowSpacing = 2
        };

        private readonly StackLayout _ContentStackLayout = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal };

        private readonly ContentView _ContentView = new ContentView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        private readonly StackLayout _ChildrenStackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Spacing = 0,
            IsVisible = false
        };

        private IList<TreeViewNode> _Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode>();

        private readonly TapGestureRecognizer _TapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        private readonly TapGestureRecognizer _ExpandButtonGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

        private readonly TapGestureRecognizer _DoubleClickGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        #endregion

        #region Internal Fields
        internal readonly BoxView SelectionBoxView = new BoxView { Color = Color.Red, Opacity = .5, IsVisible = false };
        #endregion

        #region Private Properties
        private TreeView ParentTreeView => Parent?.Parent as TreeView;
        private double IndentWidth => Depth * SpacerWidth;
        private int SpacerWidth { get; } = 30;
        private int Depth => ParentTreeViewItem?.Depth + 1 ?? 0;

        private bool _ShowExpandButtonIfEmpty = false;
        private Color _SelectedBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        private double _SelectedBackgroundOpacity = .3;
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public event EventHandler Expanded;

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the user double clicks on the node
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler DoubleClicked;
        #endregion

        #region Protected Overrides
        protected override void OnParentSet()
        {
            base.OnParentSet();
            Render();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public string NodeKey { get; set; }

        public int NodeId { get; set; }


        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => SelectionBoxView.IsVisible;
            set => SelectionBoxView.IsVisible = value;
        }
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get => _ChildrenStackLayout.IsVisible;
            set
            {
                _ChildrenStackLayout.IsVisible = value;

                Render();
                if (value)
                {
                    Expanded?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// set to true to show the expand button in case we need to poulate the child nodes on demand
        /// </summary>
        public bool ShowExpandButtonIfEmpty
        {
            get { return _ShowExpandButtonIfEmpty; }
            set { _ShowExpandButtonIfEmpty = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// set BackgroundColor when node is tapped/selected
        /// </summary>
        public Color SelectedBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return _SelectedBackgroundColor; }
            set { _SelectedBackgroundColor = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// SelectedBackgroundOpacity when node is tapped/selected
        /// </summary>
        public Double SelectedBackgroundOpacity
        {
            get { return _SelectedBackgroundOpacity; }
            set { _SelectedBackgroundOpacity = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// customize expand icon based on isExpanded property and or data 
        /// </summary>
        public DataTemplate ExpandButtonTemplate
        {
            get { return _ExpandButtonTemplate; }
            set { _ExpandButtonTemplate = value; }
        }

        public View Content
        {
            get => _ContentView.Content;
            set => _ContentView.Content = value;
        }

        public IList<TreeViewNode> Children
        {
            get => _Children;
            set
            {
                if (_Children is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollectionChanged)
                {
                    notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
                }

                _Children = value;

                if (_Children is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollectionChanged2)
                {
                    notifyCollectionChanged2.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
                }

                TreeView.RenderNodes(_Children, _ChildrenStackLayout, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset), this);

                Render();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: Remove this. We should be able to get the ParentTreeViewNode by traversing up through the Visual Tree by 'Parent', but this not working for some reason.
        /// </summary>
        public TreeViewNode ParentTreeViewItem
        {
            get => _ParentTreeViewItem;
            set
            {
                _ParentTreeViewItem = value;
                Render();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new TreeViewItem
        /// </summary>
        public TreeViewNode()
        {
            var itemsSource = (ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode>)_Children;
            itemsSource.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;

            _TapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(_TapGestureRecognizer);

            _MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            _MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            _MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            _MainGrid.Children.Add(SelectionBoxView);

            _ContentView.GestureRecognizers.Add(_TapGestureRecognizer);

            _ContentStackLayout.Children.Add(_SpacerBoxView);
            _ContentStackLayout.Children.Add(_ExpandButtonContent);
            _ContentStackLayout.Children.Add(_ContentView);

            SetExpandButtonContent(_ExpandButtonTemplate);

            _ExpandButtonGestureRecognizer.Tapped += ExpandButton_Tapped;
            _ExpandButtonContent.GestureRecognizers.Add(_ExpandButtonGestureRecognizer);

            _DoubleClickGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 2;
            _DoubleClickGestureRecognizer.Tapped += DoubleClick;
            _ContentView.GestureRecognizers.Add(_DoubleClickGestureRecognizer);


            _MainGrid.Children.Add(_ContentStackLayout);
            _MainGrid.Children.Add(_ChildrenStackLayout, 0, 1);
            

            base.Children.Add(_MainGrid);

            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

            Render();
        }

        void _DoubleClickGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: This is a little stinky...
        /// </summary>
        private void ChildSelected(TreeViewNode child)
        {
            //Um? How does this work? The method here is a private method so how are we calling it?
            ParentTreeViewItem?.ChildSelected(child);
            ParentTreeView?.ChildSelected(child);
        }

        private void Render()
        {
            _SpacerBoxView.WidthRequest = IndentWidth;

            if ((Children == null || Children.Count == 0) && !ShowExpandButtonIfEmpty)
            {
                SetExpandButtonContent(_ExpandButtonTemplate);
                return;
            }

            SetExpandButtonContent(_ExpandButtonTemplate);

            foreach (var item in Children)
            {
                item.Render();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use DataTemplae 
        /// </summary>
        private void SetExpandButtonContent(DataTemplate expandButtonTemplate)
        {
            if (expandButtonTemplate != null)
            {
                _ExpandButtonContent.Content = (View)expandButtonTemplate.CreateContent();
            }
            else
            {
                _ExpandButtonContent.Content = (View)new ContentView { Content = _EmptyBox };
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers
        private void ExpandButton_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ExpandButtonClickedTime = DateTime.Now;
            IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO: Hack. We don't want the node to become selected when we are clicking on the expanded button
          //  if (DateTime.Now - _ExpandButtonClickedTime > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50))
          //  {
                ChildSelected(this);
        //    } 
        }


        private void DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleClicked?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        private void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeView.RenderNodes(_Children, _ChildrenStackLayout, e, this);
            Render();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and the TreeView control :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Involys.PraxisDemo.Controls.InCustomTreeView
{
    public class TreeView : ScrollView
    {
        #region Fields
        private static StackLayout _StackLayout = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical };

        //TODO: This initialises the list, but there is nothing listening to INotifyCollectionChanged so no nodes will get rendered
        private static ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode> _RootNodes = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode>();
        private TreeViewNode _SelectedItem;


        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The item that is selected in the tree
        /// TODO: Make this two way - and maybe eventually a bindable property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty RootNodesProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RootNodes), typeof(IEnumerable<TreeViewNode>), typeof(TreeView), null,
                                            BindingMode.Default, null, OnRootNodesChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(TreeViewNode), typeof(TreeView), null,
                                    BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public IEnumerable<TreeViewNode> RootNodes
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerable<TreeViewNode>)GetValue(RootNodesProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(RootNodesProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public TreeViewNode SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (TreeViewNode)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }


        }




        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the user selects a TreeViewItem
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler SelectedItemChanged;


        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public TreeView()
        {
            _StackLayout = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical };
            Content = _StackLayout;
        }
        #endregion


        //selection
        #region Internal Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: A bit stinky but better than bubbling an event up...
        /// </summary>
        internal void ChildSelected(TreeViewNode child)
        {
            SelectedItem = child;
            child.IsSelected = true;
            child.SelectionBoxView.Color = child.SelectedBackgroundColor;
            child.SelectionBoxView.Opacity = child.SelectedBackgroundOpacity;
            RemoveSelectionRecursive(RootNodes);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void RemoveSelectionRecursive(IEnumerable<TreeViewNode> nodes)
        {
            foreach (var treeViewItem in nodes)
            {
                if (treeViewItem != SelectedItem)
                {
                    treeViewItem.IsSelected = false;
                }

                RemoveSelectionRecursive(treeViewItem.Children);
            }
        }
        #endregion
        //end selection

        #region Internal Static Methods
        internal static void RenderNodes(IEnumerable<TreeViewNode> childTreeViewItems, StackLayout parent, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, TreeViewNode parentTreeViewItem)
        {
            if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                //TODO: Reintate this...
                parent.Children.Clear();
                AddItems(childTreeViewItems, parent, parentTreeViewItem);
            }
            else
            {
                AddItems(e.NewItems.Cast<TreeViewNode>(), parent, parentTreeViewItem);
            }
        }

        static void OnRootNodesChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("source changed");
            if (oldvalue is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollectionChanged)
            {
                notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    RenderNodes((IEnumerable<TreeViewNode>)newvalue, _StackLayout, e, null);
                };
            }

            RenderNodes((IEnumerable<TreeViewNode>)newvalue, _StackLayout, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset), null);

        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Static Methods
        private static void AddItems(IEnumerable<TreeViewNode> childTreeViewItems, StackLayout parent, TreeViewNode parentTreeViewItem)
        {
            foreach (var childTreeNode in childTreeViewItems)
            {
                if (!parent.Children.Contains(childTreeNode))
                {
                    parent.Children.Add(childTreeNode);
                }

                childTreeNode.ParentTreeViewItem = parentTreeViewItem;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

so in my viewmodel I create my `TreeViewNode` and bind it to `RootNodes` property of TreeView. so I added :

```
private ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode> _treeviewSource;
        public ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode> TreeviewSource
        {
            get => _treeviewSource;
            set
            {
                _treeviewSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreeviewSource);
            }
        }
```

But raising property changed while having a big list of TreeViewNode takes waaay too much time. And that is my problem ... I suppose the problem is that it notifies the UI foreach TreeViewNode(stacklayout) in the list and that what it takes time.

I Hope you guys can help with that. Thanks

Comment: "I suppose the problem is" - the first step in fixing a performance issue should be determining exactly what the problem is, not guessing.  What have you done to validate your assumptions about the cause of the problem?

Comment: @Jason I was debugging ! its the line where it raises PropertyChanged ( ``` RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreeviewSource); ```` ) that takes around 15-20 seconds. So 
 I thought maybe there is something that have to do with the fact that  TreeViewNode inherits from StackLayout

Comment: Consider to use `BatchBegin / BatchCommit` in your `RenderNodes` method (and, maybe, in other methods which make a lot of adding/deleting operations).

Comment: Are you following some example?  `ObservableCollection` and `PropertyChanged` are designed to be used with **model** data, not with `View` types.  Start over. Research how to [Create a "Custom Layout Class" in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom). You'll write code behind to build up the UI hierarchy before it is displayed.